# Why are some of my gradients from tf.gradients() 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement DDPG in tensorflow and I'm having a problem where a bunch of my gradients are 0 and weights never update.  Specifically, when I use tf.gradients to find the gradients of the actor's output with respect to its weights many of them are 0.  My network is fully connected (Dense) with two Relu layers followed by a tanh, so I don't see how any of the gradients should be 0.  I've also tried a linear output layer just to see and have the same problem.

Here is how I am taking the gradients.  value_grads seems fine when I print it.

```
self.value_grads = tf.gradients(self.critic.output, self.critic.input)
self.param_grads = tf.gradients(
     self.actor.output,self.actor.trainable_weights,
     grad_ys = self.value_grads[0][:,6:])

self.updateActor = self.Adam.apply_gradients(
   list(zip(self.param_grads,self.actor.trainable_weights)))
```

The last part of the critic input is the output of the actor (actions) which is what the array slicing is for.  The problem is the same if I leave grad_ys as the default.

My models are defined in Keras as

```
def actor_model_init(self,lr):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(400, input_dim=6, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))
        return model
def critic_model_init(self,lr):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(400, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
        return model
```

When I print out self.actor_weights and grad_ys I get:
gradients:

```
[[[-0.0157675687 0.0120204324 0 ... 0 0.0208223816 -0.0349246264]
 [-0.00571825635 0.00396730239 0 ... 0 0.00937585346 -0.0138687501]
 [-0.0158380773 0.0105671259 0 ... 0 0.0250782985 -0.0364054628]
 [-0.0158380773 0.0105671259 0 ... 0 0.0250782985 -0.0364054628]
 [-0.0288313236 0.0195191056 0 ... 0 0.0462683141 -0.0670839325]
 [-0.0282119 0.0190116 0 ... 0 0.0459179357 -0.0661953315]], [-0.00791903865 0.00528356293 0 ... 0 0.0125391493 -0.0182027314], [[0.0113580525 -0.171025231 0 ... 0 0 0.00811411068]
 [0.00957783218 -0.102332 0 ... 0 0 0.00356913568]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0.0111253224 -0.128508702 0 ... 0 0 0.00531342905]
 [0.00626153918 -0.124018401 0 ... 0 0 0.00682871882]], [0.0142762065 -0.213435426 0 ... 0 0 0.00935945194], [[-0.000175745212 0.00259550055]
 [-0.112493247 0.958190382]
 [0 0]
 ...
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [-5.41314e-05 0.000472108193]], [-0.0436145514 0.362336487]]
```

actor weights:

```
[[[0.0054333806 0.12122912 0.0479801297 ... 0.0306232758 0.104769051 -0.0758013055]
 [0.0759132877 -0.0792496726 -0.104717404 ... 0.0820670947 0.0845757276 0.115226477]
 [0.0852553844 0.114217594 0.00587947667 ... -0.109474026 0.0511197932 -0.00158583815]
 [0.0148470057 -0.0479621775 0.0104149431 ... 0.0410911106 -0.100606494 -0.0555957966]
 [0.0467446335 0.0142703867 -0.099080056 ... -0.041407384 0.11107491 0.106032036]
 [0.101174556 0.0360424556 0.0209118873 ... -0.0135738291 0.0136910854 0.0971500501]], [-0.00377752353 0.00614813669 0 ... -0.00220888574 -0.00626849663 0.00305078411], [[-0.0534874797 -8.69747601e-05 -0.066062957 ... -0.00342122815 0.104449756 0.0936678797]
 [0.0770198926 0.103114337 0.0361573808 ... 0.0649240315 -0.0637648925 -0.000988217071]
 [0.084307462 -0.0977794454 -0.0771790445 ... 0.0954664052 0.0909464359 -0.0377970114]
 ...
 [-0.072436884 0.0706674233 0.0323147923 ... -0.00516427308 0.0530067384 0.094952]
 [-0.0498984344 -0.0488674156 -0.0538246594 ... -0.00791313685 0.0444330312 0.0678459927]
 [-0.11838764 0.0993790403 0.0238035 ... 0.0809683651 0.109502122 -0.110104255]], [-0.000307052454 0.0118757728 -0.00224457239 ... -0.00128154433 -0.00476269191 -0.00587580958], [[0.249329627 0.235500798]
 [0.501975 -0.528630257]
 [0.0883877 -0.53192538]
 ...
 [-0.509910524 0.0830168799]
 [-0.418986678 -0.384885371]
 [-0.399918109 0.196372628]], [0.00718917884 0.0016854346]]
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? relu and linear activations could produce zero gradients, but what's the exact problem?

Comment: The code runs, I just find it suspicious that certain weights in my network never get updated no matter how long I run it for.  If the gradient is always zero wouldn't that imply that it's not even connected?

Comment: It may be a dying rely case and you can try adjust learning rate or use leaky relu. But it's a pretty broad topic